# Add field in drop down in ANGULAR 6?

Tags: user-interface, angular6

I want to have a filter in my UI which is a drop down kind of input. The fields in that drop down are populated from an API call from backend. I want to manually add one more field in that , How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectize.js which will help you to create a input type dropdown. Refer API Documentation for its use and different events. I have used selectize.js with jquery in angular 6 project so i can use all events but you can also use npm for selectize if it suits your requirements better.

https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/